# insert data to sqlite and sql server in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlite

i have a main form name call fTest.cs

in this main i have button to save data to sql server and sqlite

here is my code

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dictionary<String, String> dataSqlite = new Dictionary<String, String>();
            Dictionary<String, String> dataSqlserv = new Dictionary<String, String>();
            dataSqlite.Add("name", "puja");
            dataSqlite.Add("score", "3232");
            dataSqlserv.Add("ID", "32");
            dataSqlserv.Add("Name", "puja lagi");


             cDatabaseSQLite.Insert("highscore", dataSqlserv);
            cDatabaseSQLite.Insert("highscore", dataSqlserv);
            cDatabaseSQLite.Insert("highscore", dataSqlserv);

            cDatabaseSQLServer.Insert("tblTest", dataSqlite);
            cDatabaseSQLServer.Insert("tblTest", dataSqlite);
        }
```

and i calling insert method in cDatabases.cs

```
public bool Insert(String tableName, Dictionary<String, String> data)
        {
            switch (sqlType)
            {
                case DATABASE_SQL_TYPE.DATABASE_SQL_TYPE_SQLITE:
                    return cSQLite.Insert(tableName, data);
                case DATABASE_SQL_TYPE.DATABASE_SQL_TYPE_MSSQL:
                    return cSQL.Insert(tableName, data);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

here is insert in my sqlite database

```
public bool Insert(String tableName, Dictionary<String, String> data)
        {
            String columns = "";
            String values = "";
            Boolean returnCode = true;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> val in data)
            {
                columns += String.Format(" {0},", val.Key.ToString());
                values += String.Format(" '{0}',", val.Value);
            }
            columns = columns.Substring(0, columns.Length - 1);
            values = values.Substring(0, values.Length - 1);
            try
            {
                this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("insert into {0}({1}) values({2});", tableName, columns, values));
            }
            catch (Exception fail)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(fail.Message);
                returnCode = false;
            }
            return returnCode;
        }
```

and this is the sql server insert database

```
public bool Insert(String tableName, Dictionary<String, String> data)
        {
            String columns = "";
            String values = "";
            Boolean returnCode = true;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> val in data)
            {
                columns += String.Format(" {0},", val.Key.ToString());
                values += String.Format(" '{0}',", val.Value);
            }
            columns = columns.Substring(0, columns.Length - 1);
            values = values.Substring(0, values.Length - 1);
            try
            {
                this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("insert into {0}({1}) values({2});", tableName, columns, values));
            }
            catch (Exception fail)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(fail.Message);
                returnCode = false;
            }
            return returnCode;
        }
```

when i try to debug and push the button save the data can't save to sqlite and server, or the data is empty. how to insert the data?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what happened? Did you get an exception? Did your executenonquery code actually run when you debuged it?